# Testing UI for azure web app on iPad

Tags: web-development, ios, debugging, azure

I am working on debugging my mobile application.  There is a specific requirement/issue that I am having related to a drag and drop touch interface on an iPad.  I am at the trial and error phase of trying to figure out how to fix this (meaning I have no idea how to fix the issue I'm seeing).

The only way I have been able to figure out how to test my app on a mobile device is to deploy it to my azure test instance because the azure compute emulator always runs sites under 127.0.0.1.  This is really annoying since each deploy to azure takes 10+ minutes.

So my question is, how the heck to people do mobile development on this platform?    I've have found some people suggesting I could set up a [reverse proxy using fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625075/how-to-connect-to-the-azure-compute-emulator-remotely-to-test-a-web-role-from-an) to allow remote connections but so far I haven't been able to get this to work.  Is there some sweet ios simulator that I haven't been able to find?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar specifically with the azure compute emulator, however setting up a reverse proxy should be fairly straightforward. 
I would suggest using nginx, you're config file should be this:

```
 server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
```

*the proxy_pass should go to whatever port the emulator is running on

Ubuntu Install:
sudo apt-get install nginx

Windows Install:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: Thanks for your help.  how would you change this to work with ssl?

Comment: Nginx has SSL support, you just need to link your certificates: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule
You would probably want another server block that listens on 443, so that both http and https will work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying/tweaking the offending code into [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) from my laptop.  Then I navigated to the JSfiddle on my iPad.  Still a pain, but much faster than azure deploy.  Helped alot!

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335491/how-to-debug-javascript-on-an-ipad-running-through-a-webview) has some helpful tips for how to debug javascript from iPad.